Spring Boot Java 11 in Debian 12 with tomcat10
I've switching a Java 11 spring boot war to tomcat10 on Debian 12 from Debian 11 and want to build with maven using existing definitions in a pom.xml file.
I don't want to use:

Java 17
Jakarta replacements for javax
Spring starter version 3.0.x
Pre built war file

I'd like to use/keep:

Java 11 (installed from oldstable)
Spring-data-solr

I'm open to updating the:

Maven plugins
Jacoco
Changing to com.mysql

But can I install a natively built war into /var/lib/tomcat10/webapps-javaee ? I found that the war doesn't explode or when if I can get it to explode the endpoints are not visible. The Catalina logs contains nothing special. It builds 100% successfully. I have alternatives set to use java 11.
What am I missing?
And how can you debug it, it's like a black box that reports nothing back to the administrator.

There is a contradiction in your requirements:

you want to use Tomcat 10
you don't want the jakarta replacements for javax

Tomcat 10 requires that you use the jakarta replacements for javax - i.e. it loads only servlets that implement jakarta.servlet.Servlet and completely ignores servlets that implement javax.servlet.Servlet (that switch was done with the Servlet Specifications 4.0.3 and 5.0)
If you don't want to switch from javax.servlet.Servlet to jakarta.servlet.Servlet your only option is to stay with Tomcat 9.

Thank you for this @Thomas. This answers part of my question. I've tried the migration tool which fails. And replacing javax with jakarta for something like: javax.validation.constraints.NonNull seems non-trivial. I'm not a java expert, but I reckon there is 1000-2000 lines of code changes between tomcat9 and tomcat10 for my code stack, and no longer support for solr, so its a mess. By the way, my only concern is meeting CVEs in the future....
